# Docker doesn't see app in FastApi after moving to other folders

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi

I'm having trouble with docker build with python and fastapi framework. It seems like docker doesn't see the python app package in the container after building.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./app /app
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
```

This is my structure:

```
├── app
│   └── main.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── Dockerfile
```

Inside the app folder there's also other folders and every one of them has an empty `__init__.py` file. This is the start of my `configurator.py` file (invoked in `main.py`):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles

from app.config.vendor import Vendor
from app.api import home, file_api
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
File "/app/config/configurator.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.config.vendor import Vendor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

It's like the moment python moves inside some folder, it can't see app anymore and can't go back.

Comment: Could you share detailed structure of your project?

Comment: Is this work outside of the container? My guess is that the import is not right, should be something like  `from app.config.configurator.vendor import Vendor`?

Comment: Try adding the root folder to the PYTHONPATH: `ENV PYTHONPATH /`